# While filling in a form only update the form do not reload the whole page

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have got the following form:

```
    <form action="" method="get" target="_self">
    <select name="Category" class="dropmenu" id="Category"onchange="this.form.submit()">
                     <option value="">Any</option>
                     <option value="Keyboard"<?php if ($_GET['Category']=="Keyboard") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Keyboard</option>
                     <option value="Piano"<?php if ($_GET['Category']=="Piano") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Piano</option>
                   </select>
   <select name='Manufacturer' class="dropmenu" onChange="this.form.submit()" >

             <?php  
                  echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($RS_Search1)) {
        $selected = $_GET['Manufacturer'] == $row['Manufacturer'] ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected.'>' . $row['Manufacturer'] . '</option>';
    } ?>        </select>
    <select name="Color" class="dropmenu" onChange="this.form.submit()">
                     <?php  
                  echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
                 while ($Color = mysql_fetch_array($RS_Search2)) {
        $selected2 = $_GET['Color'] == $Color['Color'] ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option '.$selected2.'>' . $Color['Color'] . '</option>';
    } ?>  </form>
```

Second form to submit

```
<form action="search2.php" method="get">                   </select><input name="Category" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['Category']; ?>">
    <input name="Manufacturer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['Manufacturer']; ?>">
    <input name="Color" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['Color']; ?>">
                   <select name="price" class="dropmenu">
                     <?php  
                  echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
                 while ($Price = mysql_fetch_array($RS_Price)) {
        $selected3 = $_GET['price_range'] == $Price['price_range'] ? 'selected' : '';
            echo '<option '.$selected3.'>' . $Price['price_range']. '</option>';
    } ?>


      </select><input name="Search2" type="submit"  id="Search2" value="Submit">



</form>
```

As you can see the option values are pulled from a db, after the first value is chosen. What the form does at the minute is reload the whole page. Is there a way to just reload the form in stead of reloading the whole page. I need to keep the values that are submitted on change of a option value to be able to fill in the next drop down menu.
Any help welcome.

Comment: Look into AJAX to submit forms without refreshing the page.  Side note, mysql_* functions are deprecated.  Use PDO or mysqli, with prepared statements.  You're open for sql injection as is.

Comment: You must be a heck of a mind reader to know he/she is vulnerable for sql injection since you can't see his queries :)

Comment: @Mattt  True, I don't see the queries.  Judging by the coding style though, I'd bet good money that my statement is still true.  Echoing out `$_GET` parameters without sanitizing the info isn't safe either, since it's open for XSS attacks.  In any event, the mysql_* functions *are* deprecated, and prepared statements prevent forgetting to sanitize an input and leaving yourself vulnerable.  Glancing at the code, it looks like that vulnerability has a good shot at being present.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson completely agree, just having some fun with ya.

Comment: @Matthew, [you'd be right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362718/third-drop-down-menu-does-not-populate-from-database)!

Comment: @halfer Bahahahaha....Always feels good to be right :)  So sad that OP could lose all their data even after the warning :)

Comment: @Matthew: odd, I think I can hear some Evil Cackling in here `;-)`