# Third drop down menu does not populate from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have got the following Index.php:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)    {       
            try{            
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try{
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getColor(CategoryId) {     

        var strURL="getColor.php?Category="+CategoryId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('qcolor').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }       
    }
    function getBrand(CategoryId,ColorId) {     
        var strURL="getBrand.php?Category="+CategoryId+"&Color="+ColorId;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if (req) {

            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('qbrand').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }               
            }           
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Quick_find_2">
         <div id="Quick_find_container">
           <form action="search2.php" method="get">
             <div id="qcategory_1">Product</div>
             <div id="qcategory">
               <select name="Category" class="dropmenu" id="Category" onChange="getColor(this.value)">
                 <option value="">Any</option>
                 <option value="Keyboard">Keyboard</option>
                 <option value="Piano">Piano</option>
               </select>
             </div>

             <div id="qcolor_1">Colour</div>
             <div id="qcolor"><select name="Color" id="Color" class="dropmenu">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
        </select>

             </div>
             <div id="qbrand_1">Brand</div>
             <div id="qbrand"><select name="Manufacturer" class="dropmenu">
                 <option value="">Any</option> </select>

             </div>
```

Please note the form is not ready yet it will need a submit button in the end, however for now I just want to populate the drop down menus
The first two menus work fine I'm having trouble populating the last third one.
The getColor.php contains the following code:

```
$Category= $_GET['Category'];
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
    $query="SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM products WHERE products.Category LIKE '%$Category%'  AND Category!= 'Stage Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Keyboards' AND hidden ='no' ORDER BY Color";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    ?>
    <select name="Color" onchange="getBrand(<?=$Category?>,this.value)">
    <option value="">Select Color</option>
    <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['Color']?>><?=$row['Color']?></option>
    <? } ?>
    </select>
```

The getBrand.php contains this code:

```
$Category=$_GET['Category'];
$Color=$_GET['Color'];

mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query="SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer FROM products WHERE products.Category LIKE '%$Category%' AND Color = '$Color' AND Category!= 'Stage Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Keyboards' AND hidden ='no' ORDER BY Manufacturer";
$result=mysql_query($query);


?>
<select name="Manufacturer">
<option value="">Select Brand</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value="<?=$row['Manufacturer']?>"><?=$row['Manufacturer']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Please don't worry about SQL injection as I will sort that.

Somehow the values for the $Category and Color are not being passed trough can anybody see where I'm going wrong? Any help welcome

Comment: If it was me, I'd just gather all the data in one big query, and handle the display logic entirely within php/javascript without any need for further hits on the db.

Comment: Thanks for looking, Do you have a suggestion on how to do this as I am not really familiar with java.

Comment: Color is ok, but Manufacturer is problem. right?

Comment: Whats the result you getting in gerBrand.php from DB?

Comment: The Color if fine. the output from the getBrand is noting, it doesn't populate the drop down menu

Comment: for Manufacturer option value contain double quotes but not in for Color. Plz check that also.(this may not be the problem)

Comment: Sorry that's not it still not working

Comment: java isn't javascript (I know; it's confusing) but there are hundreds of examples out there of dependent drop downs with javascript

Comment: make sure your query is correct. It contains so many  Category!= part. So at first check the query gives any result. Also you can try another query to check whether it is working.

Comment: @deepus Thanks for your comment. I have checked that by changing the $Category and $Color to actual values, which works fine it just doesn't work when retrieving the $_GET values. Not sure if there is a mistake in the javascript function getBrand

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating the third menu based on previous dropdown values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365172/populating-the-third-menu-based-on-previous-dropdown-values)

Comment: This was duplicated by your later question, but since the other one has attracted a helpful answer, I will vote to close this one. Please only ask questions once: duplicating essentially the same thing without declaring the duplicate risks creating wasted effort.

Comment: [Booooobbbbbyy Taaaables](http://bobby-tables.com)...Sanitize user input.  Prepared statements and mysqli or PDO will save you a lot of heartache later on down the road!