# Populating the third menu based on previous dropdown values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have three drop down menus the first two work fine, the third one is giving me same head aches.
For some reason once the second drop down values changes it loses the value of the first menu. Here is the code:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
            var xmlhttp=false;  
            try{xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e){try{   xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }catch(e){
                    try{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(e1){
                        xmlhttp=false;
                    }}}
                return xmlhttp;
        }
        function getColor(CategoryId) {     

            var strURL="getColor.php?Category="+CategoryId;
            var req = getXMLHTTP();

            if (req) {

                req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        // only if "OK"
                        if (req.status == 200) {                        
                            document.getElementById('qcolor').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                        } else {
                            alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                        }
                    }               
                }           
                req.open("GET", strURL, true);
                req.send(null);
            }       
        }
```

Until here it all seems to work the rest the is something wrong but not sure what:

```
function getBrand(CategoryId,ColorId) {     

    var strURL="getBrand.php?Category="+CategoryId+"&Color="+ColorId;
    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                    document.getElementById('qbrand').innerHTML=req.responseText;                       
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }               
        }           
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}
```

The HTML Code:

```
 </head>
    <body>
    <div id="Quick_find_2">
             <div id="Quick_find_container">
               <form action="search2.php" method="get">
                 <div id="qcategory_1">Product</div>
                 <div id="qcategory">
                   <select name="Category" class="dropmenu" id="Category" onChange="getColor(this.value)">
                     <option value="">Any</option>
                     <option value="Keyboard"<?php if ($_GET['Category']=="Keyboard") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Keyboard</option>
                     <option value="Piano"<?php if ($_GET['Category']=="Piano") {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Piano</option>
                   </select>
                 </div>

                 <div id="qcolor_1">Colour</div>
                 <div id="qcolor"><select name="Color" id="Color" class="dropmenu">
        <option value="">Select Color</option>
            </select>

                 </div>
                 <div id="qbrand_1">Brand</div>
                 <div id="qbrand"><select name="Manufacturer" class="dropmenu">
                     <option value="">Any</option> </select>

                 </div>
```

The getColor.php

```
<? $Category= $_GET['Category'];
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query="SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM products WHERE products.Category LIKE '%$Category%'  AND Category!= 'Stage Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Keyboards' AND hidden ='no' ORDER BY Color";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="Color" onChange="getBrand(this.value)">
 <?php  
              echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
             while ($Color = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $selected2 = $_GET['Color'] == $Color['Color'] ? 'selected' : '';
    echo '<option '.$selected2.'>' . $Color['Color'] . '</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

Here is the getBrand.php

```
<? $Category= $_GET['Category'];
$Color=$_GET['Color'];
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query="SELECT DISTINCT Manufacturer FROM products WHERE products.Category LIKE '%$Category%' AND Color = '$Color' AND Category!= 'Stage Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Keyboards' AND hidden ='no' ORDER BY Manufacturer";
$result=mysql_query($query);


?>
<select name="Manufacturer">
<option value="">Select Brand</option>
<? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<option value=<?=$row['Manufacturer']?>><?=$row['Manufacturer']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

This out puts the color correct, however once changed to selected it will not echo out the Category value or at least when I try to get in the the getBrand file it can not be found is there a way to send this value of the Category as well to the getBrand file?

Any help welcome

Comment: Is this [a duplicate of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23362718/third-drop-down-menu-does-not-populate-from-database)?

Comment: (Voting to close the other one, as there are no answers on that one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your getColor.php file:

A: you are not passing the value attribute in option tag.

B: In `getBrand` function you are getting **two** variables; one is `CategoryId` and other one is `ColorId`, but in the `Onchange` function of Brand select box you are passing only one value, `THIS.VALUE`.

Edited code:

```
<? $Category= $_GET['Category'];
mysql_select_db($database_dconn, $dconn);
$query="SELECT DISTINCT Color FROM products WHERE products.Category LIKE '%$Category%'  AND Category!= 'Stage Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Pianos' AND Category!= 'Recent Keyboards' AND hidden ='no' ORDER BY Color";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="Color" onChange="getBrand('<?php echo $Category; ?>',this.value)">
<?php  
          echo '<option value="">Any</option>';
         while ($Color = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$selected2 = $_GET['Color'] == $Color['Color'] ? 'selected' : '';

echo '<option '.$selected2.' value="'.$Color['Color'].'">' . $Color['Color'] . '</option>';
} ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I understand this, however I am not sure how to solve it, could you please point me in the right direction, cause I'm sure this is where the problem is.

Comment: @Ria..Now try this out

Comment: Thanks you so much, you can't believe how long I have been looking for an answer.

Comment: @Vishal: wherever you see a SQL injection, it is worth pointing it out in your answer. I think the OP is aware in this case, though.