# three select lists database driven

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, select

I am trying to create a form with three select dropdown lists. user selects an option from select1 and based on the selected option, select2 gets populated, then user selects an option from select2 and based on selection, select3 gets populated.

following an example on stackoverflow I created this. the lists are getting populated fine but values are not passed when I hit submit button. if i select options from select1 and select2 only then values do get passed, but when i select option from select3 then no values are passed.

This is my PHP:

```
            <?php
          require "php/db.inc";
          $db = new mysqli($hostName, $username, $password,'mms');//set your database handler

          $query = "SELECT AcID, AcName FROM accounts WHERE ParentAcID ='0'";
          $result = $db->query($query);

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $accountgroups[] = array("id" => $row['AcID'], "val" => $row['AcName']);
          }

          $query = "SELECT AcID, AcName, ParentAcID FROM accounts";
          $result = $db->query($query);

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $accounts[$row['ParentAcID']][] = array("id" => $row['AcID'], "val" => $row['AcName']);
          }

          $query = "SELECT AcID, AcName, ParentAcID FROM accounts";
          $result = $db->query($query);

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $subaccounts[$row['ParentAcID']][] = array("id" => $row['AcID'], "val" => $row['AcName']);
          }

          $jsonAcGroup = json_encode($accountgroups);
          $jsonAc = json_encode($accounts);
          $jsonSubAc = json_encode($subaccounts);
        ?>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  <?php
    echo "var account_group = $jsonAcGroup; \n";
    echo "var accounts = $jsonAc; \n";
    echo "var sub_accounts = $jsonSubAc; \n";
  ?>
  function loadAccountGroup(){
    var select = document.getElementById("AcGroupSelect");
    select.onchange = updateAccount;
    for(var i = 0; i < account_group.length; i++){
      select.options[i] = new Option(account_group[i].val,account_group[i].id);          
    }
  }
  function updateAccount(){
    var catSelect = this;
    var catid = this.value;
    var subcatSelect = document.getElementById("AcSelect");
    AcSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    subcatSelect.onchange = updateSubAccount;
    for(var i = 0; i < accounts[catid].length; i++){
      subcatSelect.options[i] = new Option(accounts[catid][i].val,accounts[catid][i].id);
    }
  }

  function updateSubAccount(){
    var catSelect2 = this;
    var catid2 = this.value;
    var subcatSelect2 = document.getElementById("SubAcSelect");
    SubAcSelect.options.length = 0; //delete all options if any present
    for(var i = 0; i < sub_accounts[catid2].length; i++){
      subcatSelect2.options[i] = new Option(sub_accounts[catid2][i].val,sub_accounts[catid2][i].id);
    }
  }


  function start() {
    loadAccountGroup();
    updateAccount();
    updateSubAccount();
                   }
    window.onload = start;  
</script>
```

This is my FORM:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="form_test.php">

<table class='table table-striped'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Companyname" class="control-label">Account Group</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Companyname" class="control-label">Account</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Companyname" class="control-label">Sub Account</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Companyname" class="control-label">Debit</label>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Companyname" class="control-label">Credit</label>
          </div>
        </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="AcGroupSelect" id='AcGroupSelect'></select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="AcSelect" id='AcSelect'></select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="SubAcSelect" id='SubAcSelect'></select>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="col-sm-1 form-control" name="DebitAmount" placeholder="Debit Amount">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="col-sm-1 form-control" name="CreditAmount" placeholder="Credit Amount">
          </div>
        </td>

    </tr>



</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. this script works just fine. the problem was not in the script but rather in the html. the top menu was hiding one line output n i was banging my head for getting the blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Once you get your values from the drop down list you still need to somehow put them into you form and submit them.
 have a look at this I managed to solve it like this.
[Populating the third menu based on previous dropdown values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365172/populating-the-third-menu-based-on-previous-dropdown-values/23365583#23365583)

Also have you got a submit button? Can't see how you submit in your form. Also missing closing form tag

Comment: Yes I have the submit button and closing tag. it just didn't get copied. Ill try your solution.. thanks

Comment: Finally I figured it out. this scripts works just fine. the problem was not in the script but rather in the html.